# Run all commands as Administrator on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

I'm having issues with permissions on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I'm used to (from Windows Server 2003) being able to open up a CMD prompt and type something like: `copy \some\file /y' and overwrite a file in the current directory.

The permissions on the directory/file allow modifying by 'Administrators', but I get `Access is denied.` unless I specifically run the cmd.exe 'as Administrator' which is unacceptable for how I need to manage my server. I need to be able to on-the-fly perform tasks without having to go and open a new cmd prompt, switch to the directory, retype the command, etc.

So how can I make it so my user who is a member of Administrators can by-default, run commands as an Administrator?

Answer (score 2):

I would never recommend this, but here goes

On a stand-alone Windows Server 2008 R2, do the following:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Choose User Accounts -> User Accounts
3. Click "Change User Account Control Settings"
4. Take the Slider down to the bottom where it says "Never Notify"
5. Press OK.
6. Press OK in your last UAC Prompt

Comment: +1 I would never recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking "how do I bypass UAC?" Well you can't bypass UAC. You can turn off UAC however.

From this [relevant blog post by Margosis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/06/29/faq-why-can-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt.aspx):

> Having said all that, there is a Local Security Policy option to
>   change the behavior of the elevation prompt for Administrators to
>   "elevate without prompting". With this option selected, anything that
>   requests elevation gets elevated without prompting the user. (The
>   default setting is "prompt for consent"; the third option is "prompt
>   for credentials". Note that "elevate without prompting" is available
>   only for members of the Administrators group. The options for standard
>   users are "prompt for credentials" and "automatically deny elevation
>   requests".) While "elevate without prompting" may be useful in
>   well-constrained, secure environments for automated testing and
>   possibly for initial system setup, having this option selected
>   otherwise is very risky and strongly discouraged. (Note also that
>   Vista's Home SKUs do not include the policy editor.)

Answer (score -1):

I always have this issue on a new Win 2008R2 server.  The problem is in the Start Menu properties. (I always forget this.)

Right Click  and choose Properties.  On the Start Menu tab select . In the context menu find "Enable context menus and dragging and dropping" and check the box.  Then

Now when you right click a program in the start menu you will get the pop-up with the options like "Run as administrator", "Pin to Taskbar", etc.

Now you just have to remember to start your PowerShell or cmd window with Run as Administrator.